# Verbes -ELER / - ETER au futur simple

Tags: phonétique, futur-simple

Pourquoi est-ce qu'on double les L/T ou ajoute un accent grave quand on fait le futur simple des verbes qui terminent par -ELER/-ETER? Je sais qu'on fait ça quand le E suivant est muet, mais j'entends qu'on le prononce quand on dit "appell**e**rai" ou "jett**e**rai", par exemple.

Comment: Je pense que vore confusion vient de la dénomination "e muet" qui est trompeuse: le e dit "muet" peut être prononcé notamment entre 2 consonnes. On parle plutôt de "e caduc". Cf. https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_caduc

Answer (score 1):

> Je sais qu'on fait ça quand le E suivant est muet, mais j'entends
>   qu'on le prononce quand on dit "appellerai" ou "jetterai"

Le *mais* me fait penser que vous voyez là une contradiction.

De fait, il n'y a aucun *e* muet nulle part.

Pas plus dans l'infinitif du verbe *appeler* que dans le *appellerai* du futur puisque vous dites très justement l'entendre. (Encore que cela soit devenu de moins évident)

Une formulation autre conviendrait peut-être mieux :

*on fait ça quand le E suivant **serait muet... sinon**.*

Toute cette histoire est la faute à... la position de l'accent tonique en français :

Lorsque, comme c'est le cas dans *appellerai*, un mot se termine par une voyelle, l'accent tonique est, par défaut, sur l'**avant dernière syllabe.**

Dans ces conditions, le *e* composant l'avant dernière syllabe ne peut nécessairement pas être muet. Il faut tout au contraire que la voix puisse s'y poser.

Oui, l'accent tonique en français n'a cessé de s'estomper, cette nécessité n'est donc plus un impératif d'élocution mais... les conjugaisons sont restées.